# Unity Package Name Have To Match com.Company.ProductName? IOS, Android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, package-name

I'm developing an app for IOS and Android using Unity. When I set a package name does it have to match the com.CompanyName.ProductName convention? I desire to have spaces and special characters unsupported in the PackageName, like &()? in my product name, as that's the name that appears on in the mobile launcher under the app. But this will make my package name no longer fit the convention. Is this OK? Or should I avoid those characters all together and simplify the name so it has no spaces or special characters? Here's an example:

CompanyName: Example

ProductName: Are We There Yet? (2018)

PackageName: com.Example.AreWeThereYet2018

Is this OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is ok. There is no check that these name match, but it just make your life easier when you identify your app.

The example you gave is a good way to choose a package name that kind of matches the actual name

Comment: That said...you should own the `example.com` domain. E.g. Google will publish apps with the com.google.xyz identifier. If you do not own a domain, use a TLD that doesn't exist (or at least makes it clear you weren't trying to use a valid domain), eg. `game.phedg1.yxz`